# Is it possible to save log of Ruby on Rails delayed job log in database, instead of in delayed_job.log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Currently the application that I'm working on is using Ruby on Rails. The application use `delayed_job.log` file to log the delayed job activity. However, the application is hosted in Openshift environment, using pod, and if the pod is deleted, and if a new pod is created, the application will make a new `delayed_job.log` file. One of the proposed solution from an engineer in the company is to save the log in a table in a database. How can I do that? The goal is to save the information that written in `delayed_job.log` file to a table in database, instead of `delayed_job.log` file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That should be possible. You can configure the logger in DelayedJob with `Delayed::Worker.logger =`. You would only need to write a class that has the same interface as the [default `Logger`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) that comes with Ruby (that means methods like `add`, `log`, `info`, `debug`, ...) and that then writes the into a database instead of a file.